# htaccess - Simple rewrite rule not triggering

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to match a simple rule to rewrite a url but it's just not matching. I want to redirect
**https://example.com/web/thanks/**
to
**https://example.com/thanks.php**

Here's what I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^thanks/$ https://example.com/thanks.php [R=302,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^thanks/$ https://example.com/thanks.php [R=302,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/thanks/$ https://example.com/thanks.php [R=302,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^web/thanks/$ https://example.com/thanks.php [R=302,L]
```

and many more tiny variations but none of them are triggering. I tried using [this online tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and it returns "This rule was not met". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to redirect instead of rewrite? And what does "not trigger" mean? What do you get, a 404 not found, 500 server error, or something else?

Comment: The last one should work, btw. At least should it redirect the client to the PHP file.

Comment: I get a 404 since https://example.com/web/thanks/ doesnot actually exist. By not trigger, I mean the rule doesnot match and I don't get redirected.

Comment: And yes, I would like to rewrite. So the url remains the same. I figure that's whats gonna happen when it works?

Comment: So `/web/thanks` doesn't redirect. Do you get redirected when you enter `/web/thanks/` (*with* trailing slash)? When using the last rule.

Comment: No that is not working but this worked `^(.*)thanks/$`. But like you said, I'm getting redirected. I want the url to not change

Comment: The third rule cannot work, because the pattern starts with a leading slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite, just use your last rule

```
RewriteRule ^web/thanks/?$ /thanks.php [L]
```

with the following changes

- no [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), this is only relevant for some relative URLs
- optional trailing slash `/?`, if you want both `/web/thanks` or `/web/thanks/` to work
- no domain name, because this might trigger a redirect instead of a rewrite, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

  > **Absolute URL**
  >   If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.
- no [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag, because this triggers a redirect instead of a rewrite

---

The pattern `^.*thanks/$` or `^(.*)thanks/$` also works, but it matches any URL ending in `thanks/`, like `/hellothanks/`, `/areyousurethanks/`, `/some/path/thanks/`, ...

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I need that action so I'll keep the `^(.*)thanks/$`. And I removed `R` to remove the redirect